# stop callable option iPhone

Tags: html, css

Gd day
I have inside a project, a mobile browser version 
On iPhone, all numbers are callable

i want to select all callable numbers and stop the call options

example:

```
<div>123456789</div>
<span>123456789</span>
<p>123456789</p>
<p>1234,567,89</p>
```

what i want to say that numbers are used with different tags: div, span, p ...

is there a solution using CSS, to let me select all affected numbers by call option (only the callable numbers, not all) ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

It will prevent IOS from auto-formatting phone numbers

---

If you can't access the HTML, you should be able to prevent the styling of the numbers from changing *and* prevent clicking with something like this:

```
a[href^=tel]{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

The above *should* work on IOS.

Comment: i dont have access to the html, i can only change with css, is it feasible ?

Comment: ok, now i removed the styling but still need to stop the callable function